# How to convert a lengthy Word document to a single image?

Tags: images, conversion, microsoft-word-2007

In my Microsoft Word 2007 document there is a text format board. I want to convert this document to an image but can't take a screenshot of the entire file due to its length. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a picture that is embedded in that Word document into a JPG file for example? (because that is easy, just want to verify first)

Comment: I want to turn a board containing texts into an image file. I want to create an image copy of the board.

Comment: Any reason not to take a picture of the screen? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool

Comment: the board is long in height !

Answer (score 2):

1. Zoom out and take a screenshot. If the text is large enough to still be readable this should suffice.
2. There are lots of online Word document to image converters, so search the net and try a few.
3. Use a virtual printer driver such as [ImagePrinter](http://code-industry.net/imageprinter.php) (can print any file to BMP/PNG/JPG/TIFF/PDF):

   [image: 1]
4. Use any screenshot utility that supports **scrolling window capture**, such as [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html), [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), [HyperSnap](http://www.hyperionics.com/hsdx/), [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/en/) etc.